# Ending a nintex workflow through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, workflow, sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

Hopefully someone has an answer out there and I am just unable to find it. My question is:

**Is there a way to end a Nintex workflow (on a list item) through the use of JavaScript?**

*Points I've come across while researching today:*

- Nintex uses the old SharePoint 2010 Workflow Engine
- There is no supported web service for ending a workflow, see;

  http://SharePointPortal.local/site/subsite/_vti_bin/Workflow.asmx
- There is little/no documentation on JavaScript usage of the
  `getWorkflowInteropService` method.

Note that we are using SharePoint Server 2013 (part of the issue I believe).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: this might help, then have to use SOAP
https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1048

Answer (score 0):

There is a web service action to terminate a workflow: [TerminateWorkflow](http://help.nintex.com/en-US/sdks/SDK2013/#Reference/SOAP/NW_REF_SOAP_TerminateWorkflow.htm)

You will need to build the soap request in JavaScript. The documentation has an example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
   xmlns:nin="http://nintex.com">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <nin:TerminateWorkflow>
         <nin:listId>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</nin:listId>
         <nin:itemId>0</nin:itemId>
         <nin:instanceId>4f3d251f-3e3d-4065-8784-8d698868f429</nin:instanceId>
      </nin:TerminateWorkflow>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

It also has a response sample:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <TerminateWorkflowResponse xmlns="http://nintex.com"/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```